# Можно ли с помощью JQuery получить значение кастомного атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, в разметке присутствует таблица, где в каждом теге tr есть атрибут href.

С помощью JQuery я вешаю обработчик клика на каждую tr.

Я могу в обработчике события через event.target получить значение href элемента, который возбудил данное событие?

Пытался через attr() это сделать, но получаю неопределенность.

Если нужно, то могу привести код.

Вот так я генерю разметку:

```
<tr id="clickable" href="'@(Url.Action("Details", null, new {storageId = storage.StorageId}))'">
```

Далее вешаю обработчик:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("#clickable").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(e.target);
            $.get(target.attr("href"), function (data) {
                $("#dialogContent").html(data);
                $("#modDialog").modal('show');
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Так вы href хотите из tr получить?

Comment: _Если нужно, то могу привести код._ - без него не ясно, что за _неопределенность_ ты получаешь и как

Comment: скорее всего лишние кавычки вот тут `href="'...'"` оставь какие-нибудь одни. в остальном все должно работать именно так, как и ожидалось

Comment: @Grundy, все равно не находит атрибут.

Comment: добавь разметку, что у тебя находится внутри строки. Используй `this` вместо `e.target`

Comment: Почему вы вместо невалидного `href` не используете валидный `data-` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#clickable").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="clickable" href='@(Url.Action(" Details ", null, new {storageId = storage.StorageId}))'>
    <td>clickable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Кто минусует, хотя бы пишите почему. Способ ведь рабочий.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А разве this и event.target не должны иметь одинаковые элементы и работать?

Comment: @iluxa1810 честно говоря, не в курсе, но, судя по всему, нет. Нужно будет обязательно разобраться в этом моменте)

Comment: @iluxa1810, `this` - это элемент, на котором висит обработчик, а `event.target` - Это элемент по которому действительно кликнули

Comment: _preventDefault_ - не нужен, так как у tr нет никаких особых действий по  умолчанию, которые нужно было бы предотвращать. минус за непонятный кусок кода, неизвестно чем отличающийся от кода в вопросе, и без каких либо пояснений.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, поправил

Answer (score -1):

```
$('tr').on('click', function (e) {
  // e - элемент, на котором произошло событие
}
```

Comment: Т.е если я вызову attr на e, то смогу получить значение href?

Comment: конечно, потому что e - это конкретный элемент из 100 ваших tr. Тот, на который кликнули.

Comment: А event.target не тоже самое?

Comment: кстати, да - какой href у tr?

Comment: покажите, как этот tr обернут в <a> или содержит <a>

Comment: Он не обернут. Я подумал, при генерации разметки запихать ссылку в самопальный href, а потом в обработчике его читать и вызывать модальное окно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Так и получайте `.attr()` не из `$(this)`, а из `$(this).find('a')`. Или у вас все сложнее?